# matplotlib duplicate figure and apply changes

Tags: matplotlib

I'm making a series of figures with the same layout. As the layout is taking many lines of codes, I'm trying to duplicate the first once done and change only a few things, such as markers, and if possible the data though I know it might complicate things as it would need probably rescaling and so that at the end at 'plt.show()' command, the original figure plus the duplicated get displayed.

Comment: If you mean what you think you mean, I'd probably just take all that layout and put it into a function so you can just call the function as many times as you want

Comment: I'm already doing so, but duplicating would give so much more flexibility with so lesser code lines. Using a function does not let me change anything I want easily. There should be a way to do so. This is what I was using the most when I was working in Origin.

Comment: Maybe I don't understand what you mean, then ... if you make your function return the figure and axes objects, you can modify all you want very easily.  Are you just using the pyplot interface or the actual object interface?  I highly recommend the latter over the former, e.g. `ax.plot()` rather than `plt.plot()`

Comment: If your function can extract all info about the layout of a given figure and can apply them to a newly created figure, that should be perfect. I'm always using fig = plt.figure; ax = fig.add_subplot(xxx), ax.plot()

Comment: It would also help if you paste some code so people can give you an example solution.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure that "duplicating settings" in the way you describe is really feasible ... it probably requires lots of low-level access of all the objects involved in the layout (the axes, the axis objects, the line objects, patch objects, etc.)  I could be totally wrong about that, but that's my instinct.  I've put here something which may do close to what you want, though, as in not having to duplicate a lot of layout specifications.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def make_layout(data):
    fig = plt.figure()

    ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

    p, = ax.plot(data,'o')

    p.set_markerfacecolor('green')
    # Presumably lots of complicated settings here

    return fig, ax, p

data = np.linspace(0,1)

f1, a1, p1 = make_layout(data)
f2, a2, p2 = make_layout(data**2)

# Make the tweaks you want
a2.set(axis_bgcolor='m')
p2.set_markerfacecolor('yellow')
```