# Python figure and axes object

Tags: python, matplotlib, figures

I have a big unresolved question about the `matplotlib` Python module.

If I create a figure called `[Figure1]`, with 2 axes `[Ax1, Ax2]`, and another figure `[Figure2]`, is there a function or method that will allow me to export the `Ax1` object from `Figure1` and redraw it to the `Figure2` object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general axes are bound to a figure. The reason is, that matplotlib usually performs some operations in the background to make them look nice in the figure.

There are [some hacky ways around this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6309472/matplotlib-can-i-create-axessubplot-objects-then-add-them-to-a-figure-instance#comment18919455_6309636), also [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27763875/matplotlib-duplicate-axes-or-figure), but the general consensus seems to be that one should avoid trying to copy axes.

On the other hand this need not be a problem or a restriction at all.

You can always define a function which does the plotting and use this on several figures like so:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def plot1(ax,  **kwargs):
    x = range(5)
    y = [5,4,5,1,2]
    ax.plot(x,y, c=kwargs.get("c", "r"))
    ax.set_xlim((0,5))
    ax.set_title(kwargs.get("title", "Some title"))
    # do some more specific stuff with your axes

#create a figure    
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1,2)
# add the same plot to it twice
plot1(ax1)
plot1(ax2, c="b", title="Some other title")
plt.savefig(__file__+".png")

plt.close("all")

# add the same plot to a different figure
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(1,1)
plot1(ax1)
plt.show()
```